# Replacing HAVING with WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, having

```
SELECT team, sum(maths)
FROM marks
GROUP BY team
HAVING sum(maths) = (
    SELECT max(sum(maths))
    FROM marks
    GROUP BY team
)
```

There are three teams A,B,C with some no of members in it.

First using `SELECT max(sum(maths)) FROM marks GROUP BY team` I am obtaining the max sum of maths.

Now using the entire query I am trying to display the team who got the highest sum on maths.

How can I rewrite the query so as to replace the `HAVING` with `WHERE`.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: using oracle..  and sqlplus

Comment: Why do you ask this question?  Your query is correct and clear.

Comment: why do you want to use `WHERE`? well in fact your quesry will return your expected result.

Comment: looking for multiple ways to implement the same query and see which one is best way for me. Also it increases the understanding level of the queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select * from (
  select team, v maxmarks, row_number() over (order by v desc) RNum from(
    SELECT team, sum(maths) v
    FROM marks 
    group by team 
  )x
)xx where RNum=1;
```

Comment: @techdo - the OP wants the team with the highest marks as well, not just the marks value.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replace HAVING with WHERE, but there is no benefit in doing so.

```
select team, sum(maths) from
(
   SELECT team, sum(maths) as total
   FROM marks
   GROUP BY team
) t1
where t1.total = ( select max(t1.total) from t1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you order your results, you can wrap them in an outer `SELECT` that restricts it to the first row, using the [`ROWNUM` pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT team, sum(maths)
    FROM marks
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY sum(maths) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Or you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER` analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm), again wrapping in an outer select:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT team, sum(maths),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY sum(maths) DESC) AS rn
    FROM marks
    GROUP BY team
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not more efficient than others,but if you just want multiple ways,you can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(TEAM) OVER(ORDER BY SUM(MATHS) DESC),
          FIRST_VALUE(SUM(MATHS)) OVER(ORDER BY SUM(MATHS) DESC)
FROM MARKS
GROUP BY TEAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using a common table expression:

```
with team_sum as (
  select   team,
           sum(maths) sum_maths
  from     marks
  group by team)
select *
from   team_sum
where  sum_maths = (
         select max(sum_maths)
         from   team_sum)
```

For very large numbers of teams it would perform well, as the optimiser can materialise the result set of the team_sum common table expression and perform the max() on it.

It also lists multiple teams where they share the same total score.